# List object properties from a instance in Jena

Tags: list, jena, object-properties, object-property

How can I list all Object Properties associated to a instance in Jena?

For example:
A **Person** has an Object Property called "**hasVehicle**" which is associated with a class **Vehicle**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate Jena method is `OntClass.listDeclaredProperties`. There are some nuances to be aware of; the Jena [RDF frames how-to](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/rdf-frames.html) explains in detail.

**Update**

OK, I've looked at your code sample, and read your description, and I'm afraid I don't understand what you want to do. What I've done is re-write your code sample so that it does something that I *guess* you might want, based on your description in the comment:

```
package test;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class LeandroTest
{
    public static String NS = "http://www.owl-ontologies.com/TestProject.owl#";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, null );
        FileManager.get().readModel( m, "./src/main/resources/project-test.owl" );

        OntClass equipe = m.getOntClass( NS + "Equipe" );
        OntProperty nome = m.getOntProperty( NS + "nome" );

        for (ExtendedIterator<? extends OntResource> instances = equipe.listInstances(); instances.hasNext(); ) {
            OntResource equipeInstance = instances.next();
            System.out.println( "Equipe instance: " + equipeInstance.getProperty( nome ).getString() );

            // find out the resources that link to the instance
            for (StmtIterator stmts = m.listStatements( null, null, equipeInstance ); stmts.hasNext(); ) {
                Individual ind = stmts.next().getSubject().as( Individual.class );

                // show the properties of this individual
                System.out.println( "  " + ind.getURI() );
                for (StmtIterator j = ind.listProperties(); j.hasNext(); ) {
                    Statement s = j.next();
                    System.out.print( "    " + s.getPredicate().getLocalName() + " -> " );

                    if (s.getObject().isLiteral()) {
                        System.out.println( s.getLiteral().getLexicalForm() );
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println( s.getObject() );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following output, by first listing all resources of `rdf:type` `#Equipe`, then for each of those it lists the resources in the model that link *to* that Equipe, then for of those linked resources it lists all of the RDF the properties. I don't think that's a particularly useful thing to do, but hopefully it will show you some patterns for traversing RDF graphs in Jena.

```
Equipe instance: Erica
Equipe instance: Etiene
  http://www.owl-ontologies.com/TestProject.owl#EtapaExecucao_01
    EtapaExecucao_DataModificao -> 2010-03-29T10:54:05
    caso_de_teste -> http://www.owl-ontologies.com/TestProject.owl#CasoDeTeste_01
    EtapaExecucao_StatusTeste -> Passou
    EtapaExecucao_Reprodutibilidade -> Sempre
    type -> http://www.owl-ontologies.com/TestProject.owl#EtapaExecucao
    EtapaExecucao_VersaoDefeitoSurgiu -> Release ICAMMH_01.00
    EtapaExecucao_Severidade -> Minimo
    EtapaExecucao_VersaoDefeitoCorrigiu -> Release ICAMMH_02.00
    DataExecucao -> 2009-07-10T09:42:02
    EtapaExecucao_StatusDoDefeito -> Nao sera corrigido
    EtapaExecucao_DataSubmissao -> 2009-06-30T09:43:01
    Tipos_Fases -> http://www.owl-ontologies.com/TestProject.owl#FaseTesteExecucao
    EtapaExecucao_Resolucao -> Fechado
    executor_do_teste -> http://www.owl-ontologies.com/TestProject.owl#Etiene
    EtapaExecucao_PrioridadeCorrecao -> Normal
Equipe instance: Fabio
Equipe instance: Melis
```

Some general suggestions, particularly if you have any follow-up questions:

- ask *specific* questions, it's very hard to answer a vague unclear question;
- provide *runnable* code if possible: you can take my code below, drop it into a code environment like Eclipse and try it out
- provide the code and data *in the question*, not linked off on pastebin
- take some time to reduce the code and data to the minimum form necessary to show the problem: your Protégé file was over 600 lines long

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner look my code, now I can't get a object property for any instance that I list, just list data type property and their values.
Can you show me a code with list object property? I just need the name of instance associated with my current instance in for.

Comment: I can't run your pastebin code without the data. Also, for the sake of archiving this question for the future (which is one of the goals of StackOverflow), please paste a complete runnable example (including data) into the question rather than put it in a separate pastebin.

Comment: Hi @Ian thanks for answer, my archive ProjectTest.owl is http://pastebin.com/dufPZCd9 

look for example:
I have a resource 'Etiene' was a relationship with instance 'Etapa Execucao 01' through Property called 'executor_do_teste' but I can't identify this, in my code.
I'm miss this link between they.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Ian that's exactly I wanted.
I have another question, if I have data in a database and want to transform it into OWL instances, there is an automated way on Protégé or only creating a class jena to transform?

Comment: One of the aims of StackOverflow is to collect and curate good answers to programming questions, for future reference. Therefore, each page should be about just one question. If you have another problem, please post a new top-level question.You may find this other answer useful as background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891459/best-way-to-create-a-sparql-endpoint-for-a-rdbms-mysql-database